Understanding why a beta distribution fits to my data
Apparently my statistics knowledge is confronted with something I cannot grasp.
I have set of data, which basically should sort images into a binary classification (let’s say young and old, and for further discussion I label them as 0 and 1).
Unfortunately this data set with which I should work is a histogram with the x axis being a (almost) continuous score of the two binary outcomes. For example, there are data points which are in the bin 0.65. I would interpret this as more ppl said in the survey that this image belongs to the classification 1.
Funnily, and I’m new to the beta distribution, the data I have fits astonishing well a beta distribution with parameters 5.94 and 2.42.
I read so much in the last weeks about statistics, beta distributions and the connection to the binomial but it’s completely mind bending. I’m really wondering why this data set I got is apparently following a beta distribution.
My thoughts so far were, that I have n images and for every image let’s say I have k ppl asking them the question:”belongs this image to class 0 or 1”. Since I have now for every image k answers I can understand why there are fractional scores (between 0 and 1 and not just 0 and 1) as an outcome. I can also understand that this question might follow a binomial distribution - but why follows the result a beta distribution and not a binomial?
I know this might be an easy question for an experienced person, but I had no contact to these problems so far and would like to learn.
Thx a lot for any insights
Edit: Adding more information to clarify the question
So here’s my data set (black dots) fitted with a beta distribution (I normalized the histogram to 1, therefore you don’t see the counts in the bins but rather the density as I understand it)

The reduced chi^2 is about 1.35, that’s why I would consider this fit very good. The remark “astonishing” was more because apparently I don’t (or didn’t) understand the beta distribution well enough.
From what I read today, the beta distribution can be used if p is unknown in a binomial experiment. That seems to make sense, since p is not known (or was not known) before the experiment.
The statement about sorting was unclear. The sorting is not done by me and of course the sorting is not done by the data set. The data set is rather the outcome of the sorting into the binary labels.
However, the sorting has been done by asking for each picture a bunch of persons and let them put the picture into the two labels. Afterwards, for each image the score was evaluated as a percentage of answers 1 vs the total number of answers. Therefore my predecessor created that histogram.
I guess what my fit to histogram with the beta could mean is that it’s a probability distribution of the probability for each single picture being put in the label 1. Interpreting the parameters of the beta as the number of successes and failures makes some sense to me, but I’m not sure how to interpret this.
I hope someone can clarify this and I have to apologize for the unclear question in the first place

Edit: Thanks for pointing out the error bars, JimB.
Indeed, the error bars are constructed from counting statistics, I.e. $\sqrt{counts}$, I had no better guess and the total number of images is 2068. So fairly close to the guess of JimB.
The value of k is always the same. Would it make a strong difference if there would be a variation of k on the 1% level?


It's an impossible question for anybody because you don't provide any details about the distribution of your data.  Could you show us how you know it is fit with a Beta distribution and how you determine that is "astonishing"?

It is surprising if you have a good fit with those parameters, as an uninformed outsider I might have guessed some pictures might have a high probability of being guessed "young" by most people and others of being guessed "old" by most people, with fewer pictures having intermediate values.

A set of data cannot "sort images". It's very unclear what data you have, or how you (the data analyst, not the data) are using it to sort things.

What do the vertical bars around each dot represent?

What are the typical values of $k$?  Are they always the same or nearly the same?  Do you have those values of $k$ for each image?  It appears from your figure that the "error bars" are symmetric around the plotted points and identical for those points with the same vertical value so those error bars must be from some formula you can certainly give in your question.  My guess is that your "histogram" is constructed from 1,974 images (as the discreteness of the vertical values implies that the smallest values are associated with a count of 0, then next highest values with a count of 1, etc.

Thanks for pointing these questions out JimB. I added a 2nd edit to clarify this.

My current understanding is that if I would add another image, the value of p for the binomial experiment (I.e. asking 100 people if it’s a 0 or a 1) would be beta distributed. Is that correct? And what does it mean for the ensemble average of these images since all images are taken from the same object?

You still haven't actually told us what k is. 100 or 1000 is important, because really the number of 1 classifications per image would be beta-binomial(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution). Unrelated: I also wonder how your images differ?

I just read about the beta-binomial and it seems that the expectation value using the above parameters (k = 100, $\alpha = 5.94$ and $\beta = 2.42$). Do I understand it correct that every image follows a beta-binomial with the above parameters? And can $\alpha$ and $\beta$ still interpreted as number of successes and failures? Concerning the images: it is a perception experiment and the images were taken from the same building in different lighting, weather, season conditions and at a vast amount of viewing angles. The persons asked should evaluate if the building is old or new.

You mentioned your predecessor created that histogram; does that mean you don't have access to the original data? I think if it was me I'd start over with the raw data and make my own counts and my own histogram (with integer counts and no error bars).

I do have access to the original data in the sense that I have all the images used and the aggregated score for each image. Luckily, the survey was done with a tablet and hence the summing of the score for each image was done automatically. From my intuition, I would have also just done that histogram for the start. It is clear that in this experiment, there are “no errors” for the counts. However, every measurement has an error and I’m used in this case to estimate the error. Since it’s counting, I used the Poisson statistics.
